# Flash/AS3: How do I access <Instance Name> object from the Document class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In Flash CS4, I can give an object in my timeline an instance name via the properties pannel. I figured this variable would be available to me in my Document class, but when I try to access it, it's null.

How can I get access to these instance from within my Document class? Also, do the objects have to be in the timeline at frame 1 in order to be available to my Document class's constructor?

Comment: did you try getChildByName("name_of_object").  Not sure if automatically declare stage instances was in cs4

Comment: yes- and it returns null. The object isn't in the timeline yet, so I can see why I can't access it. I just need a way of knowing when to call getChildByName("obj_name"). That might help.

Comment: use: Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED -- this'll tell you when everything is created.  Your code is in the constructor?  You made sure you gave the item a name? :)

Comment: currentTarget on Event.FRAME_CONTSTRUCTED always seems to be [object Main]. Should I be looking for something else there? Also, yes code is in the constructor and my item has a name.

Comment: currentTarget is the DisplayObject that a bubbling event is currently "on" as it's bubbling through the chain of DisplayObjects depending on "what level" an event listener is at that's what the currentTarget will be.  target of the event will be the object that initially dispatched the event.

Comment: sorry- I should have been more clear, e.target and e.currentTarget both return my main document class [object Main]

Comment: When event.frame_constructed is fired on the doc class, it should be built fully.  Then you should be able to access what's in the document class.  To be honest, in the constructor it should be there already, constructor should fire after frame_constructed.  Are you sure your objects are there the next frame?  (numChildren)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is always the first thing called on an object, it is used to get the memory necessary to store all the properties for that object type.  After an object is constructed then (assuming it's a display object) at some point it's added to the stage.  If an instance of one of your objects is added to the stage on a frame then the main document class will have to know when that object was added to the stage to appropriately access it.  You could create the instance of the object within your document class constructor then when added to stage fires on your main class you could add the instance.

Just attempted this wasn't able to reproduce the OPs initial behavior, I'm able to access the instance that is added on frame 1, posted some examples here:

http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestHandleOnInstance/TestHandleOnInstance.as

http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestHandleOnInstance/TestHandleOnInstance.swf

http://www.shaunhusain.com/TestHandleOnInstance/TestHandleOnInstance.fla

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "then when added to stage fires on your main class you could add the instance". If I add an Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE listener to the main class, that only fires once, when the document loads. It's almost like I want to add an ADDED_TO_STAGE listener to my instance, so that it can tell the main class that it's there. Only, I can't access the instance until it's added. I would say, create the instance in main and addToStage in main, but then I can't edit the object directly in my timeline.

Comment: @Thomas, yup you seem to be following my intention directly I was thinking in terms of removing the instance from the timeline and controlling it's creation/addition from within the document class, this way you know when the instance is valid and added to the stage.  The only other way I can think of is to listen for enter frame events until you're able to obtain a non-null reference, or to listen for added to stage events fired from the stage and check the event.target until it matches the class and/or instance you're looking to get a handle on.

Comment: adding stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, test) in my main class's constructor doesn't fire. Is there I different event I should be using?

Comment: @Thomas hey so I just gave this a shot, I was seeing like you that added to stage wasn't fired for the instance I had added via the timeline, however I also saw that in the constructor call for my main document class myMCInstance was already created and I'm able to modify properties on it without error (to clarify I'm on CS 5.5 for the Flash IDE, saving as a Flash CS4 fla didn't seem to matter, posting it to my server to link here)

Comment: hmm... I don't know why I don't have access to this object in the constructor. However, I've decided the best thing to do is just create a Class behind the movie clip and add my event listeners there. That seems to work.

Comment: "The constructor is always the first thing called on an object".  This is not true for classes in the library that have shapes, etc created on them.  The constructor is fired after all the items have been constructed, hence the FRAME_CONSTRUCTED event.

Comment: If an object isn't created/the constructor isn't called then the reference to it has nothing to point to.  FRAME_CONSTRUCTED is fired by the player on elements in the display tree which means they have been both created/constructed and the have been added to the display tree.  More on the events the player dispatches here: http://blog.johannest.com/2009/05/22/the-movieclip-life-cycle-event-frame_constructed-and-event-exit_frame/ (granted I understand you can do things in FRAME_CONSTRUCTED on other objects before the instances for that frame are created).

Comment: There is however the caveat of static members (methods/variables/properties), which can be used without any call to the constructor.  However you can never just define an instance and not call a constructor to assign it a reference and just start making calls on the members, so var something:Object; something.doSomething; will throw a null pointer exception because something was never constructed.